# Can't launch QtCreator debugger since XCode update to version 6

Tags: xcode, qt, debugging, qt-creator

Xcode updated itself to version 6 and now I can't launch QtCreator in debug mode. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Is there any error message that you can show here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [known bug in Qt Creator](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-13077). The workaround is simple: in Window->Views, show the debugger command log, then start the debug session, wait a a bit for it to get stuck, and hit Enter from within the command line in the debugger command log.

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt this patch created for LLDB 320.x in Xcode 6.01

```
git fetch https://codereview.qt-project.org/qt-creator/qt-creator refs/changes/16/95516/2 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```