# Qt Creator debugger doesn't start

Tags: xcode, qt, debugging

I have a project that I am unable to debug in Qt Creator, having upgraded to XCode 6.0.1. When starting the debugger I have the following message in the *Application Output pane*:

```
Debugging starts
```

And I have the following progress bar:

[image]

Unfortunately the first line of the main() function is never called...

I tried to clean up, delete the pro.user file and remove all the part of my application ending with a simple main() function returning 0 and the problem keep happening.

If I create a new project it works.

Maybe I could find more information by having a more verbose debug. Any idea?

I'm using:

- *MacOS 10.9*
- *Qt 5.3*
- *Qt Creator 3.2*

Comment: Do you have an executable?  Is it where the debugger expects it to be?  Can you run the executable?

Comment: Did you recently upgrade XCode to 6.0.1?

Comment: @Merlin069 Yes and it doesn't debug since I did

Comment: @cmannett85 When I run the executable it works fine. It failed only when I try to debug.

Comment: I have the same problem and haven't solved it yet, but, as a work-around for now, if you display the developer log, under Window->Views, there's a button in the bottom left, before it says "Command". Press this and it continues running. Hopefully someone will know a proper fix.

Comment: Did you try to debug from console?

Comment: @Merlin069 It worked!!! You can post this as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @Jepessen I'm not using console debugger for now but what tool you would advice me for my config? I think *gdb* is not appropriate...

Comment: You must use gdb because it's the one that's be used by qy creator. Try to use it from console in order to check if your problem is related to gbd itself or to the Qtcreator interface.

Comment: @Jepessen, while Qt creator defaults to gdb, it's no longer available in OSX via XCode and the development tools as of OS X 10.9. lldb is its replacement and you can set Qt Creator to use this instead.

Comment: So use the debugger that you need from command line.

Comment: I reproduced the issue with a newer version of Qt (5.5) and the solution here doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099592/cant-launch-qtcreator-debugger-since-xcode-update-to-version-6#answer-26107023